# Use a Power Mac G5 with the Mini Displayport LCD display

Tags: mac, dvi, displayport

Is there an adapter or card that would let me use the new LCD monitor (with Mini Displayport) with the DVI Power Mac G5?

**Edit:** Looks like one's arrived:

http://www.gefen.com/kvm/dproduct.jsp?prod_id=8913

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10246&cs_id=1024604&p_id=5998&seq=1&format=2

There is cable for it, but this is male to male cable. If you are using apple's 24 inch mini-display port monitor, isn't the cable built into the monitor? If so, you cannot use this cable. You would need a female display port end.

Currently there is not a male dvi to female display port adapter available that I know of.

Comment: I think that's the opposite of what I want. The displayport in on the display end, not the computer end.

Comment: That is why i mentioned either male or female ends. Are you using apples 24 inch monitor?

Comment: Yeah, it's the 24 inch, with glossy screen.

Comment: Yah you need a male DVI to female display port cable, which does not exist at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

It is cheaper to get the cheapest PCI-X16 videocard with DP that fits the G5, and flash its BIOS for working with a mac. Get a card with decent OSX support, like a Geforce 9400M, a Radeon 2600, a Radeon 4650, a Geforce 120GT, a Geforce 130GT, a Geforce 8800GT. See XLR8YOURMAC.com for working options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DVI to Mini Display Port Converter made by Atlona.
Here is place to buy: [BZBExpress.com](http://www.bzbexpress.com/Atlona-DVI-to-Mini-DisplayPort-Converter-Model-AT-DP200.html)

Good luck